# Weird Bug in Python

Tags: python, bots

I've been recently trying to make a bot in Python but got some weird bugs. When I run my code, I get a weird output. Here's my code:

```
from random import randint
import random

welcome_message = 'Hello, I\'m Vister, your personal assistant. You can command me to do almost anything a computer can do. So, shall we get started? (yes/no)\n'
user_name_message = 'OK, what should I call you?\n'
setup_complete_message = 'That\'s it for setup!'
prompt_message = 'So, what shall I do for you today?\n'

jokes = ['Why did the student eat his homework? Because his teacher told him that it would be a piece of cake!', 'How do you stop an astronaut’s baby from crying? You rocket!', 'Why was 6 afraid of 7? Because 7, 8, 9.', 'Why did the cow cross the road? Because it wanted to go go to the Moovies!']

def get_user_name(message):
    user_name = input(message)

    print(f'OK, {user_name}! {setup_complete_message}')

def start(message):
    welcome_message_input = input(message)

    if welcome_message_input == 'yes':
        get_user_name(user_name_message)
    elif welcome_message_input == 'no':
        print('OK, Exiting Applcation...')
    else:
        print('Invalid Command. Try "yes" or "no".')

def prompt(message):
    command = input(message)

    if command == 'tell me a joke':
        print(jokes[randint(-1, 3)])
    elif command == 'give me a random number':
        print(random.randint(0, 1000000))
    elif command == 'give me a random number in decimals':
        print(random.random())
    else:
        print('Invalid command. Try "tell me a joke" or "give me a random number".')

start(welcome_message)
prompt(prompt_message)
```

I can only type one command, and then the program exits. That's not what I want for my program, so can somebody help?

Comment: Well, was the input "give me a random number with decimals"?

Comment: You probably only want to take input *once* in prompt, and have a loop outside it.

Comment: Your `prompt` function waits for user input three times, once for each invocation of `input`. Ask for input once, then compare the user's input with the possible choices.

Comment: what is the point of using `input(message)` when your function already gets the message as argument ???

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling `input` multiple times.  Each input only looks for one thing.  If it doesn't match, it does nothing and the next line asks for more input.  Try this:

```
def prompt(message):
    command = input(message)
    if command == 'tell me a joke':
        print(jokes[randint(-1, 3)])
    elif command == 'give me a random number':
        print(randint(0, 1000000000))
    elif command == 'give me a random number with decimals':
        print(random(0, 1000000000))
    else:
        print('Invalid command. Try "tell me a joke" or "give me a random number".')
```

Comment: also `random(0, 100000000)` will throw an error

Comment: Fixed it. But now i enter a command and it exits the program completely, not letting me enter another command. How can I fix this?

Comment: That's what `while` loops are for.